# Can I expose a Docker port to another Docker only (and not the host)?

Tags: networking, docker

Is it possible to expose a port from one Docker container to another one (or several other ones), without exposing it to the host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can link containers together and ports are only exposed for these linked containers, without having to export ports to the host.

For example, if you have a docker container running postgreSQL db:

```
$ docker run -d --name db training/postgres
```

You can link to another container running your web application:

```
$ docker run -d --name web --link db training/webapp python app.py
```

The container running your web application will have a set of environment variables with the ports exposed in the db container, for example:

```
DB_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=5432
```

The environment variables are created based on the container name, in this case the container name is db, so environment variable starts with DB.

You can find more details in docker documentation here:

https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/

Comment: This additionally exposes the environment variables. Is there a way to avoid exposing the environment variables?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. According to the documentation: *Warning: It is important to understand that all environment variables originating from Docker within a container are made available to any container that links to it. This could have serious security implications if sensitive data is stored in them.*

Comment: @r.v I think you can get around that by using `--net` instead of container linking.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, the new --net option allows definition of custom networks. Works only on Docker 1.9 and above.

Comment: Just a clarification to my comment: the `--net` option existed earlier. But new networks can now be created using `docker network create`.

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative to container linking: You can define custom "networks" and tell the container to use them using the `--net` option.

For example, if your containers are intended to be deployed together as a unit anyway, you can have them all share the same network stack (using `--net container:oneOfThem`). That way you don't need to even configure host names to have them find each-other, they can just share the same `127.0.0.1` and nothing gets exposed to the outside.

Of course, that way they expose all their ports to each-other, and you must be careful not to have conflicts (they cannot both run 8080 for example). If that is a concern, you can still use `--net`, just not to share the same network stack, but to set up a more complex overlay network.

Finally, the `--net` option can also be used to have a container run directly on the host's network.

Very flexible tool.